# Java program does not terminate after Assert.fail()

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, testng, threadpool

I have a Java program where I am trying to Fail my test at the end with Assert.fail(), but at the end of the program, the threads keeps running and program does not end.

```
@Test()
void function(){
try {
        post_call =  service.submit(new Counter(asyncUrl, input,transaction_id));
        get_call =  service.submit(new PathScanner(asyncUrl, input, transaction_id));
        
        try {     
            post_call.get();        
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            Assert.fail();          
            ex.getCause().printStackTrace();  
        }
        try {
            get_call.get();
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
             Assert.fail();
             ex.getCause().printStackTrace();
                         
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

this is a test method snippet and the test case fails also as expected but the program does not exit after Assert.fail() is called.

If i remove the assert.fail(), then it the program terminates successfully ...its just that it does not show any failure then.

Please suggest a method to terminate all active threads after Assert.fail is called.

Comment: Why don't you close them before the assert.fail() ?.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! Can you please look over your question fix typos and format your code? This will make it a lot easier for others to give understand what you are asking for. Otherwise your question will most likely be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

For terminate any test on Junit 4 add argument on annotation  **timeout**

```java
@Test(timeout=2000)
public void testWithTimeout() {
  ...
}
```

Or add rule

```java
@Rule
    public Timeout globalTimeout = Timeout.seconds(10); // 10 seconds max per method tested
```

For Junit 5

```java
@Test
    @Timeout(value = 100, unit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    void failsIfExecutionTimeExceeds100Milliseconds() {
        // fails if execution time exceeds 100 milliseconds
    }
```

More info JUnit 4 [Timeout for tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Timeout-for-tests)

More info JUnit 5 [Timeout for tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-declarative-timeouts)